# RESTful API, what if the query string isn't long enough?

Tags: rest

We have a resource collection for products: `/products`.

We want to filter this collection to only return the members which have one of a list of specific `class` `id`'s. For example:

`GET /products?classes=100,101,102`

This should return a collection of product members which have any of the classes listed.

The issue we have, is that we're working with thousands of products and classes, so the class list of `id`'s could be thousands long - too long for a query string.

I'm keen to stick to RESTful principles whenever we can, so I like the fact that the resource `/products?classes=100,101,102` when called with `GET` returns a filtered products collection.

Obviously, we could include the `id`'s list in the body in JSON format, but that would mean that the call `GET /products` won't return a representation of the state of the resource (the resource being the URL), because the body is being used to provide filter options.

What's the best way to request a collection which is filtered, but the filter options are too long to use the query string..?

Comment: Interesting question! But GET requests cannot hold a payload anyway...

Comment: You could make it a POST and put your filter criteria in the request body, but use a request header X-HTTP-Method-Override to indicate you want to treat it like a GET.  I've seen this as ways to get around PUT or DELETE not being allowed for various reasons. Seems reasonable you could do this for a GET as well. See: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HTTPPUTOrDELETENotAllowedUseXHTTPMethodOverrideForYourRESTServiceWithASPNETWebAPI.aspx

Comment: @sp00m actually [GET](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-4.3.1) requests can hold a payload, but it does not define any semantics. It is furthermore not recommended to include any payload as the request might be rejected by older HTTP servers.

Comment: @RomanVottner Oh you're right, thank you for having commented!

Comment: Isn't it the client's responsibility to construct a valid request? I mean, the API client should be able to build several queries with some sensible filter criteria limit (e.g. 1000 entities). Besides, if ids are often consecutive, specifying a 'range' parameter may be useful.

Comment: @petkov.np `id`'s will almost never be consecutive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interesting comment from @C. Smith who suggests making a `POST` call using a `X-HTTP-Method-Override` header set to `GET` and passing the `id`'s in the body. This would work.

After thinking about it we're probably going to limit the number of class `id`'s allowed in the query string, and suggest making multiple calls, breaking up the `id`'s list into say, groups of 200. Submitting more than 200 would return an error.

`GET /products?classes=1004,2342,8753...` (limited to 200 `id`'s)

`GET /products?classes=2326,3343,6981...` (limited to 200 `id`'s)

Then the results can easily be stitched together after.

This method would let you use 5,000 `id`'s for example, by doing 25 calls, which while not ideal, is ok for our use case.

Comment: Depends on your use case, but ranges may help as well, e.g. `[100-102]` instead of `100,101,102`.

Comment: `id`'s will almost never be consecutive.